# middleware continua despues del next

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo la siguiente duda con un middleware, en si el middleware funciona de
la siguiente forma:

```
function middle(variable){
  // codigo codigo
  return function(req, res, next){

    if(hrk !== 'jfk'){
      if(variable){
        next();
      }
    }


    // codigo
    // y
    // mas codigo

    next();
  }
}
```

y funciona en esta ruta una ruta:

```
router.get('/lala', middle(true), miControllador)
```

El problema es que llega a donde existe la variable que es un booleano y 
esta en `true` pero el problema es que no pasa a la siguiente funcion `middle` la cual sería `miControllador`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta utilizando `return next()`:

```
function middle(variable){
  // codigo codigo
  return function(req, res, next){

    if(hrk !== 'jfk'){
      if(variable){
        return next();
      }
    }


    // codigo
    // y
    // mas codigo

    return next();
  }
}
```